# Can't found Metrics in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I developed some http server, which returned some metrics in this format

```
Some_Metrics{host="server01", key_="system.cpu.util.usage"} 3
Some_Metrics{host="server01", key_="vfs.fs.size[/data,free]"} 7016763392
Some_Metrics{host="server01", key_="system.uname"} Linux server01 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Jul 24 03:09:40 PDT 2017 x86_64
Some_Metrics{host="server02", key_="system.cpu.util.usage"} 2
Some_Metrics{host="server02", key_="vfs.fs.size[/data,free]"} 6016763392
Some_Metrics{host="server02", key_="system.uname"} Linux server02 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Jul 24 01:09:40 PDT 2017 x86_64
```

In Prometheus in prometheus.yml
I added section

```
  - job_name: some_metrics
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['server01:8001']
    params:
      collect[]:
        - textfile
```

restart Prometheus server.

In logs module started works.

After I tred to found new metrics in Prometheus, BUT I nothing found....

Used this requests:

```
http://server01:9090/api/v1/query_range?query={host=%22server01%22}&start=1513629658.0&end=1513633258.0&step=60


http://server01:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=some_metrics&start=1513629658.0&end=1513633258.0&step=60
```

Why I not foound new metrics? How solve this problem?

Comment: A first debugging step might be to take a look at the Prometheus targets. In your case it should be http://server01:9090/targets

Comment: Thank you for attention to my question, now checked new target and view this error: "labels":{"instance":"server01:8001","job":"some_metrics"‌​},"scrapeUrl":"serve‌​r01:8001/metrics","l‌​astError":"no token found","lastScrape":"2017-12-19T12:15:20.826915394+03:00","h‌​ealth":"down"}]} May be you know how solve this problem?

Comment: maked small change in prometheus.yml, parameters     params:
      collect[]:
        - textfile - remarked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `no token found` indicates an error with parsing the metrics output of your service.

I am not certainly sure about this, but I think you are only allowed to provide numbers as values, but your uname series posts a string:

```
Some_Metrics{host="server02", key_="system.uname"} Linux server02 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Jul 24 01:09:40 PDT 2017 x86_64
```

The common way to serve this information is to put it into a label:

```
Some_Metrics{host="server02", key_="system.uname", uname="Linux server02 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Jul 24 01:09:40 PDT 2017 x86_64"}
```

Also it looks like you are writing the metrics data on your own. If so, you should also take a look at these docs:

- https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/
- https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/

---

**Edit:** You can also verify the metrics with [promtool](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/master/cmd/promtool). If you have to installed you can install it directly:

```
go install github.com/prometheus/prometheus/cmd/promtool
```

Otherwise it should be part of your Prometheus distribution.

You have to pass it via stdin, like this:

```
$ promtool check metrics < so47876976
error while linting: text format parsing error in line 3: expected float as value, got "Linux"
```

Or verify the endpoint directly by using curl:

```
$ curl server01:8001/metrics | promtool check metrics
```

This should not throw any errors. If this command succeeds and the scraping still doesn't work, there is a different problem.

Comment: tried to exclud metrics Some_Metrics{host="server01", key_="system.uname"} Linux server01 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Jul 24 03:09:40 PDT 2017 x86_64, left only Some_Metrics{host="server01", key_="system.cpu.util.usage"} 3
Some_Metrics{host="server01", key_="vfs.fs.size[/data,free]"} 7016763392 problem repeat again

Comment: I updated to answer, so it explains how to verify that the metrics output is correct.

Comment: checked by promtool, returned error: error while linting: text format parsing error in line 1: invalid metric name

Comment: It looks like the file you checked doesn't match the output you posted here since the data you posted in your question works for me (besides the uname line).

Comment: I excluded metrics by type Some_Metrics{host="server01", key_="system.uname"} Linux server01 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Jul 24 03:09:40 PDT 2017 x86_64
left only Some_Metrics{host="server01", key_="system.cpu.util.usage"} 3
Some_Metrics{host="server01", key_="vfs.fs.size[/data,free]"} 7016763392, BUT error repeated again

Comment: Prometheus try read html page, GET after request URL http://server01:8001/metrics OR read stdout python app?